# Spurious drop events after drag drop operation completes

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I've implemented dragging to external applications in my WPF application and it works. However after dropping onto a target I continue to get spurious drop events on *my* application after I bring the cursor back onto it. This continues 'forever'.

As far as I can tell from online searches after calling DragDrop.DoDragDrop() I shouldn't need to do anything else. I have tried adding some code to cancel the event but it has no effect even though it runs:

```
        private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement) sender;
        if (frameworkElement.DataContext is IDragSource dragSource)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition((IInputElement) sender);
            if (dragSource.DragCanStart(new Point {X = position.X, Y = position.Y}))
            {
                var dragStart = true;

                void OnFrameworkElementOnQueryContinueDrag(object o, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e2)
                {
                    if (!dragStart)
                    {
                        e2.Action = DragAction.Cancel;
                        frameworkElement.QueryContinueDrag -= OnFrameworkElementOnQueryContinueDrag;
                    }
                }

                frameworkElement.QueryContinueDrag += OnFrameworkElementOnQueryContinueDrag;
                dragSource.DragInitiate(sender);
                e.Handled = true;
                dragStart = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked it down to our code initiating multiple drags. Our guard logic wasn't quite good enough which meant every time the mouse moved over the source component it triggered another drag.

Tricky to debug :)